# Git. Merging changes from one file to another files WITHIN the same branch

Tags: git, merge

I have two files:

```
    master/newsletter1/file.html 
    master/newsletter2/file.html
```

newsletter1/file.html has a lot of new changes that I want to merge into newsletter2/file.html. How can I achieve this? Everything I have read seems to resolve around merging between branches, but these are in the same branch :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend using a third-party diff tool of your choice, in order to do a manual merge between the two files.
This is not about source-control (ie managing the history of versions for *one* file).
This is about reporting changes from one files to another (the source-control tool will then pick up the new version for the second file).

---

As Jefromi mentions in the comments, and as he explains in "[run git merge algorithm on two individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122948/run-git-merge-algorithm-on-two-individual-files)", [`git merge-file`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge-file.html) can actually merge two different files, provided a common ancestor is provided.

```
git merge-file <current-version> <common-ancestor> <other-version>
```

In your case, you could try with the common ancestor being identical to the current file.

```
git merge-file master/newsletter2/file.html master/newsletter1/file.html master/newsletter2/file.html
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I have used netbeans for this instead.

Comment: If you have something reasonable to use for a common ancestor, you could use `git merge-file`.

Comment: @Jefromi interesting. What if the common ancestor is the same than "current file" (ie the destination)? That could work for detecting changes introduces by the first file (the source)

Comment: This got me on the right track, but running the command does nothing in my repository. I guess that's because `<base-name>` and `<other-name>` are the same. I don't have a third ancestor to point to, unless it's possible to point to a specific commit ID, but I don't know the syntax to express that and the documentation doesn't mention it.