# How to merge 2 files in master

Tags: github, git-merge

I have 2 basically same large but very similar codes in master branch and I want to merge them together.

But all the tutorials talk about branch and master.

From my undestanding they are both in master branch. one is called `body` the other one `body.sql`.

How do i merge them?

Comment: Check this if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862173/git-merging-changes-from-one-file-to-another-files-within-the-same-branch?lq=1.

Comment: Make a temp branch where you delete `body.sql`, and then rename `body` into `body.sql`. Then merge temp branch back to master. Then delete the unused `body` file.